# How to limit the length of text in a paragraph

Tags: css, html

I have a paragraph as below, which may be of any length:

> Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and 
>   Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra 
>   and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's 
>   integrity is being undermined.

I want it to appear as:

> Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and 
>   Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra...

below is the code which populates description in my website:

currently description goes to any no. of line based on product, i need to limit this to 3 lines.

Comment: Show some code, please?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/89d22/1/

Comment: @tewathia -  i want it to be trimmed by default to some text length. button click is not required. how to achieve that?

Comment: The button click was only for demonstration, you can trim the text-length automatically by simply running the btn.onclick function code on pageload, `para.innerText = para.innerText.substr(0, 100) + '...';`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to use html and css only, your best bet would probably be to use something like:

```
p {
     width: 250px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nchW8/
source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

If you can use javascript you can use this function:

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector),
        truncated = element.innerText;

    if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
        truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
    }
    return truncated;
}
//You can then call the function with something like what i have below.
document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 107);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sgjGe/1/

Comment: wanted to do it only in css and html but facing difficulty in doing it for multiline, hence deciding to use above javascript code.

Comment: if you want to limit using characters only

p {
     max-width: 250ch;
}